# Please explain me Context class in Android

Tags: android, android-context

I'm new to Android. Can someone explain me the concept of Context class/Object. What it is? What it will be used for? Why Context class?

Comment: I think, this place is not meant for this kind of general questions. I suggest you to be more specific.

Comment: Given the state of the Android documention, this is not a general question.

Comment: this might help others. Get clear idea of concept from here  [Context Concept](http://learninbestway.blogspot.in/2014/11/context-concept-in-android.html)

Answer (score 5):

Have you seen the [android developer's guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)? it will answer your questions:

> Interface to global information about an application environment. This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android system. It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

A Context has a lot of functions, but as a developer, you primarily use it to load and access application resources.

Answer (score 5):

In programming Android applications, you will hardly ever need to use the Context class directly (not possible at all since `Context` is abstract), but you will need the child classes that derive from it like `Activity`, `Service` etc.
You might want to look these up.

Comment: That was really helpful, the API documentation completely misses this point.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of Context, like the end-user-interface that will use that code. When you are in a class you can know based on Context if you have visual screen(Activity), or a running service(Service).

To compare against some other programming example, you can think of Context is equal to Console App, GUI App, or even Applet.

Answer (score 1):

I hope if you read this source code you will have answer for the problems:

http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/content/Context.java.shtml