# what is it ApplicationContext in web server design?

Tags: java, servlets

can someone please explain to me the followings:

1. what is is `ApplicationContext` ?
2. what is the difference between `ApplicationContext` and `HttpSession`?

found this implementation but can't understand the concept.
http://mythinkpond.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/spring-application-context/

Comment: A similar post can be found [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145091/the-term-context-in-programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java EE has the concept of an `ServletContext`, which is an interface for communicating with the container that is running a Java EE application.

The Spring framework has an `ApplicationContext` class which is a way of communicating with the Spring container.  In other words, it's a high level way of communicating with the Spring framework.

An HttpSession is state maintained by an application server for a series of requests made by a client.  The HTTP protocol itself is stateless, so this is a way to keep some data about the user's interactions around.

Comment: can you please detail some more about the concept of the application Context? i don't get why the application context good for? how it makes things state-full and not stateless? thanks :)