# What exactly is context in Android and why is it needed?

Tags: android, android-context

I am new to Android development and Software development too.
I keep seeing this term called - 'context' in Android code.
I know that it's a class in android.content package, but I don't understand what exactly is it and why is it needed in so many places, especially in the constructors.

Can someone please explain this term to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please explain me Context class in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870678/please-explain-me-context-class-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests, its the context of current state of the application/object. It lets newly created objects understand what has been going on. Typically you call it to get information regarding another part of your program (activity, package/application)

You can get the context by invoking getApplicationContext(), getContext(), getBaseContext() or this (when in the activity class).

Typical use of context:

```
Creating New objects: Creating new views, adapters, listeners:

TextView tv = new TextView(getContext()); ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),..);

Accessing Standard Common Resources: Services like LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE, SharedPreferences:

context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)
getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(name, mode);

Accessing Components Implicitly: Regarding content providers, broadcasts, intent

getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,...);
```

Its copy from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android/3572553#3572553)